# Windows NT 4 Runtime errors

Tags: windows

I am battling a problem with old computer and hoping someone here can help. The computer is running Windows NT4, and is serving as an HMI for LVD Omega 1500 metal fabrication center circa 1998. A few weeks ago the usually automatically starting program (Fanuc's "Basic Operation Package 1") failed to start, outputting two different messages, depending on the user being logged in - for Administrator it is "Runtime error '5' - Invalid procedure call or argument" and for other users it's "Runtime error '9' - Subscript out of range". I have no idea how to begin debugging this, it could be related to the list of WinNT users, but that is as far as I can get...

I realize this question most likely won't benefit anyone, but hope that there is a Windows NT guru here on Stackoverflow that can give me some hints.

We are in conversation with machine manufacturer - they are doing their best to get a hard drive replacement with preinstalled software, but it's taking them very long. Plus it seems that the problem may be solvable and I'd be happy not to spend a fortune on something we may not need.

Thank you, 
Anton

Comment: Honestly.  It sounds like a corrupt system file.  So the replacement HDD is likely your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're seeing is a Visual Basic error (from what I can find and remember).  In general, you'll see a lot of MS Excel results in a Google search, but what it seems to boil down to is a missing/corrupt file.  Has anyone been "cleaning" the hard drive?  I know in the past that has been the most frequent cause...  People get bored on the night shift when a supervisor isn't around, and try and "help" IT.

Some ideas:
For something like this, I'm assuming you don't have backups.  Do you only have the one machine?  If you had another one you could compare the program directories...

Have you run "chkdsk" on the drive yet?  That could tell you if you have actual hard drive issues.

Another check would be to create another user and try it from that user - first as an ordinary user, then with administrator permissions if needed.

Hopefully that helps - it sounds to me like it's more an application than an Windows NT issue.